# exe file (simulink model build method rsim) wont update input variables?

Tags: matlab, input, exe, simulink, mat

i made exe file from simulink model using rsim method. i followed this link
[how to import mat file to simulink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209131/how-to-import-mat-file-to-simulink/29215432#29215432)
that means i made simulinks input to mat file called "suma", and then comppiled it, "suma" is a mat file I save my variables from GUI.

the problem is that when i change my variables in GUI, and the "suma" varibales in that mat file change, my exe file still uses the old values that i used to compile it.
here is the code

```
a=get(handles.abroj, 'String');

b=get(handles.bbroj, 'String');

a=str2num(a);

b=str2num(b);

save('file_path_for_suma.mat','a','b');

system('file_path_for_exe_file') %this is for starting exe file?

zbroj3=load(file_path_to_output_exe_mat_file)
```

Comment: For rsim target you normally save your variables using rsingetrtp function use -p option to the executable to specify the mat file input. Have you checked any of the examples for rsim target?

Comment: thank you, i am new in creating standalone applications so i don't know which functions to use. i see now that there are a lot of examples for rsim target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the way that Simulink works when simulating a model, and the way a simulation works when it has been converted to an executable.

A good example of the steps you will need to take can  be found here: [Using RSim Target for Parameter Survey](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/examples/using-rsim-target-for-parameter-survey.html?refresh=true).

Comment: ok, thank you,
i do all that says in this link http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/examples/using-rsim-target-for-parameter-survey.html?refresh=true

but i get error when i come to this part
rtwbuild(mdlName);

??? Error using==> slbuild_private at 210
invalid simulink object handle

Comment: Can you build any models using rtwbuild?

Comment: noup, the model i'm trying to build with rtwbuild is a simple model with 2 constant blocks, an adder and scope. i just want to add two numbers together for an example, later on i wil use more complicated models.

Comment: my bad, it should have been rtwbuild('modelname'), now i can compile it.
Thank you very much mr.Phil :)

Comment: mr.Phil could you help with this question as well?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376963/how-to-call-exe-file-made-from-standalone-simulink-model-in-m-file