# how to call .exe file (made from standalone Simulink model) in .m file?

Tags: exe, mat-file, matlab

When I use

```
!mdlname -p file.mat
```

in command window of Matlab I have no errors, but when I use the command in .m file I get error that says that mat file can not be located. I tried to put full path name for file.mat like this

!mdlname -p c:\path..\file.mat

but I still get error saying mat file can not be found (error reading parameter data from mat-file)

I tried using function `system` in m file and it works but I can't force function `system` to use file.mat like I can with `-p`.

Comment: Are the executable and the mat file in the same directory?

Comment: yes, they are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
system(['"zbroj.exe" -p zbro.mat']);
```

here is the solution, i tried and i tried and finally made it. *zbroj.exe* is a rsim exe from simulink model, *-p* is a switch that forces *zbroj.exe* to take input parameters from *zbro.mat* file.